# Variable not the same type in two different functions

Tags: python

I have two functions which print into an excel file. THe only input is the file name. Here is the code:

```
#excelpy
import excelpy

#Tinker
from Tkinter import *
from tkSimpleDialog import *
from tkFileDialog import *
```

Function Mode1

```
def Mode1(full_name):
    print full_name
    print type(full_name) 
    testwbook = excelpy.workbook(full_name) 
    testwbook.show() 
    testwbook.set_cell((1,1),'TEST1', fontColor='red') 
    testwbook.set_range(2,1,['Number','Name']) 
    m1 = testwbook.save(full_name)
    testwbook.close()
    return m1
```

Function Mode2

```
def Mode2(full_name):
    print full_name
    print type(full_name) 
    testwbook = excelpy.workbook(full_name) 
    testwbook.show() 
    testwbook.set_cell((1,1),'TEST2', fontColor='red') 
    testwbook.set_range(2,1,['Number','Name']) 
    m2 = testwbook.save(full_name)
    testwbook.close()
    return m2
```

Main

```
root = Tk()
d = str(asksaveasfilename(parent=root,filetypes=[('Excel','*.xls')],title="Save report as..."))
d = d + '.xls'
d = d.replace('/','\\')
root.destroy()  

Mode1(d)
Mode2(d)
```

And once in a while I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:\TEST\testpy.py", line 2035, in <module>
    Mode2(d)
  File ""T:\TEST\testpy.py"", line 1381, in Mode2
    print type(full_name) 
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any idea why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

Comment: looks like 'type' is overridden somewhere as a str ...

Comment: Your tabbing is...strange.  Please fix it, and give us a complete test case.

Comment: Never do `from xxxx import *`, you don't know what you're putting into your global namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only function call in the line you get the error is a call to the built-in function `type()`, so the only explanation for your error message is that you overwrote the built-in name `type` by a global name `type` pointing to a string object.  Try adding

```
print type
```

before

```
print type(full_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like somewhere you're setting a (global) variable named `type` to a string, thus overwriting the built-in `type` function.

Try searching your code for `type =` to see what turns up.

Understandably, Python would then throw that exception when you tried to call `type` (strings can't be "called").